# Interface help for a Task<T> method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, asynchronous, interface

I'm trying to decouple some concrete classes and linking using SimpleIOC from MVVMLight. This is my class and I wanted to make an interface I can then register with simpleioc

```
public class SerialisationService : ISerialisationService
{

    private static async Task<T> LoadLocalXMLAsync<T>(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            T o = default(T);
            using (IInputStream inStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                o = (T)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
            }
            return o;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return default(T);
            // ERROR HANDLING AND LOGGING
        }
    }

    private async static Task SaveLocalXMLAsync(string filename, object o)
    {
        try
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(o.GetType());
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, o);
                await fileStream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ERROR HANDLING AND LOGGING
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried a few things and can't work out how I define a generic interface for returning Task in this case.

I need to register using

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISerialisationService, SerialisationService>();
```

Comment: You can't put static methods in an interface.

Comment: Sorry. I've explained myself badly. This is the actual class. What I'm trying to figure out is what the interface should look like to represent it. I would then make this class implement that interface.

Comment: Well, @SLaks still has a point: You can't specify a static method in an interface.

Comment: Ah... I see. Sorry. I had copied my implementation from something else and didn't notice that. I actually have this working now. Will post up the code.

Answer (score 0):

The Interface:

```
public interface ISerialisationService
{
    Task<T> LoadLocalXMLAsync<T>(string filename);
    Task SaveLocalXMLAsync(string filename, object o);
}
```

The Implementation:

```
public class SerialisationService : ISerialisationService
{

    public async Task<T> LoadLocalXMLAsync<T>(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            T o = default(T);
            using (IInputStream inStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                o = (T)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
            }
            return o;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return default(T);
            // ERROR HANDLING AND LOGGING
        }
    }

    public async Task SaveLocalXMLAsync(string filename, object o)
    {
        try
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(o.GetType());
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, o);
                await fileStream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ERROR HANDLING AND LOGGING
        }
    }

}
```